# A/B testing segments post-analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, ab-test

have the data of an A/B testing experiment. We can assume that the power analysis has been done correctly, so both sets, control and treatment had the necessary samples to find stat sig results.

The thing is that within the control/treatment sets, exist 3 segments, which I would like to analyze and detect if any result within each segment is stat sig, in this case, we can't assume that power analysis was done for each one of the segments.

How can I analyze the whole experiments and the sub-segments?

My idea until now is:

For the whole dataset: perform a stat sig test

For the segments: perform a stat sig test, but adjust the alpha to a lower value, kind of a Bonferoni adjustment.

Any ideas on other methods to evaluate the segments?

Comment: Maybe one-way ANOVA could be an option? In this case you would be trying to determine whether the differences between group means (i.e., Segment A, Segment B, Segment C) within control/treatment are statistically significant.

Comment: What is wrong with your suggested method?

Comment: @IanNoriega isn't ANOVA more suitable when you have A/B/C/D testing and want to compare across groups? I'm trying to compare each segment only with their control counterpart; Segment A in control vs Segment A in treatment, etc. But not Segment A vs Segment B.

Comment: @Kozolovska insecurity.

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, there's nothing you can do to increase the power of hypothesis tests on the segments after the fact. You're stuck with the power you have. The best thing you can do is control the Type 1 error in an efficient way so you don't *lose* power.

Remember that any time you perform a hypothesis test, you risk making a Type I error. In your suggested approach, you control the Type I error in the whole dataset and the segments *separately*. It is possible to incorrectly reject the null hypothesis on the whole data **and** incorrectly reject the null of at least one of the segments. In more technical terms, you are controlling the [experimentwise error rate but not the family-wise error rate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate)

I have two suggestions.

1. I would [gate your hypothesis tests](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17240656/) of the segments behind the test of the entire population. This means you first perform a hypothesis test on the entire population and only continue to perform tests on the segments if your test on the entire population is significant.
2. The Bonferonni procedure is very inefficient. [Several other procedures](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.5990) are more powerful and still maintain the same Type 1 error rate. I recommend the Hochberg Procedure. It is explained in the link I provided. The Hommel procedure is more powerful than Hochberg, but it is more complicated and fewer people are familiar with it. Both procedures can be [implemented in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html).

To summarize, perform a hypothesis test on the whole population, then, if you reject that hypothesis, move on to testing the segments using a Hochberg procedure.

Comment: Hi, I’ve thinking about this lately, what do you think about this:

Comment: 1. We compute an overall group pairwise test (experiment-wise error), this could be via something easy like a permutation test. If it IS or NOT significant, we continue to step 2, the reason to continue is because sometimes different significant segments effects could neutralize overall effect. 2. We perform omnibus test on the segments, if it IS  significant, we go down to step 3 (gate it). 3.- We perform pairwise test on the segment adjusting our alpha to control FWER.           What do you think about this? @Eli

Comment: What do you mean by “overall group pairwise test”?

Comment: The main group analysis, before going down into the segments.

Comment: The jumping back and forth will inflate the error rate if you’re not careful. I understand your problem though: the subgroups may cancel each other out in a test of the overall mean. Let me think about. You can probably do this with a graphical testing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outcome is binary (though the following will work for any outcome), we can:

- Model an interaction between treatment and segment, and
- Test for an effect of the treatment through a likelihood ratio test.

Let's assume we have designed this experiment with the hypothesis that there is an effect and it varies by group.  Doing otherwise (looking at the data first and then forming a hypothesis) would be an invalid approach. Assume we run the experiment and our data look like

```
    txt segment     y     N
  <int> <fct>   <int> <int>
1     0 1         143  1669
2     0 2         374  1596
3     0 3         485  1735
4     1 1         211  1701
5     1 2         645  1673
6     1 3         241  1626
```

Using R, we can fit a model which allows treatment effect to vary by group using

```
model = glm(cbind(y, N-y) ~ txt*segment, data = d, family = binomial())
```

The summary of the model can be examined to determine the estimated effects of each group and treatment.  I find it easier to plot the predicted probabilities.  For the data I presented, such a plot would look like...

[image]

It certainly looks like there is an effect of treatment *and* that effect varies by group. Let's test that with a likelihood ratio test.  First, we create a null model which adjusts for group in an additive fashion.  Then, we pass our model and our null model to the `anova` function.

```
# Create a null model where there is no effect of group
null_txt_model = glm(cbind(y, N-y) ~ txt + segment, data = d, family = binomial())
anova(null_txt_model, model, test='LRT')

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cbind(y, N - y) ~ txt + segment
Model 2: cbind(y, N - y) ~ txt * segment
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1         2     182.91                          
2         0       0.00  2   182.91 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Our model leads to a reduction in deviance large enough to reject the null hypothesis.  We would conclude that the treatment effect does depend on group.  Had we failed to reject this, we could not rule out a purely additive effect of group.

The problem with this analysis is that if you've powered your experiment to detect an effect of the treatment, you've likely underpowered it for this sort of analysis.  Nothing you can do about it at this point.

Comment: Would this answer OP's question? Your likelihood ratio test shows there is no treatment by group interaction,  but the group means can still be significantly different. I interpreted OP's question as a hypothesis test on `txt` and hypothesis tests for each level of `segment`.

Comment: @Eli That is not what the test shows.  Rejection of the null in this case means Model 2 leads to a reduction in deviance larger than would be expected had the interaction terms all been 0. Let's let OP clarify what exactly they mean then.

Comment: The question came from testing a new product in tech. The questions is to test if the new product is driving overall effects *txt*, and if this overall effect is different across *segment*. From my point of view (and skills) @Eli answer seems more straightforward to understand. I knew somethings about interactions effects and ANOVA, but more on the sides on testing interactions effects in the features and on testing A/B/C/D variants, respectively. So, why Demetri could not be a valid answer? Both methods could arrive to similar results, isn't it? Btw, thank you very much to both!

Comment: @marz If the question is about heterogeneity in effects then my answer is absolutely appropriate.  There is a difference between asking "Does the effect vary across groups" and "what is the effect in each group".  The former is an omnibus test and can be assessed via my approach.  The latter is answered via estimation when the former is answered in the affirmative.  If you lack the expertise to use my approach, buy all means use Eli's.

Comment: I don’t think your approach is an omnibus test. An omnibus test determines if any model coefficients are nonzero. You used a likelihood ratio test with a nested model. The likelihood ratio tests is testing whether the additional terms in the larger model, ‘txt * segment’, improve the fit. That’s asymptotically equivalent to testing the coefficients on the interaction terms.

Comment: "if you've powered your experiment to detect an effect of the treatment, you've likely underpowered it for this sort of analysis" -- how would it be designed differently to detect group level variation